Linear independence proof for set of functions
How do I prove that this subset of real valued functions $\{x, \sin{(x)}, \sin{(2x)}\}$ is linearly independent. Here is the proof suggest in the book:
Consider the relationship $c_1 . 1 + c_2 . \sin{(x)} + c_3 . \sin{(2x)} = 0 $ (that ‘0’ is the zero function). Taking three suitable points such as
$x =\pi, x = \frac{\pi}{2}, x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ gives the system:
$c_1 = 0$
$c_1 + c_2 = 0$
$c_1 + (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})c_2 + c_3 = 0$
whose only solution is $c_1 = 0, c_2 = 0$, and $c_3 = 0$.
The reason I doubt this is that it doesn't seems general to me. Why we choose only certain set of 3 points to come up with such an equation? How is this proof generalized and correct?

Your relationship must be satisfied for every real $x$, in particular for those you have chosen.

Oh yes! but the proof only chose 3 values. How is it valid then?

Yes, because you have three unknowns.

I assume the set is ${1, \sin(x), \sin(2x)}$, not ${x, \sin(x), \sin(2x)}$?

You are showing that, if we have scalars $c_1, c_2, c_3$, then if
$$c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0$$
as functions of $x$, then $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$. That is, we are showing
$$(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0) \implies c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0.$$
Now, the principle of universal instantiation says that, when we assume (or otherwise know to be true) a "for all" statement like $(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0)$, we can infer that it holds for any particular $x$. We know it holds for $x = 0$, for example, telling us that
\begin{align*}
&(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0) \\
\implies \, &c_1 \cdot 1 + c_1 \cdot \sin(0) + c_2 \cdot \sin(2 \cdot 0) \\
\implies \, &c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 + c_2 \cdot 0 = 0 \\
\implies \, &c_1 = 0.
\end{align*}
We can do this with $x = \pi/2$ and $x = \pi/4$. All of this tells us that
$$(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0) \implies \begin{cases}c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 + c_2 \cdot 0 = 0 \\ c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 = 0 \\
c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + c_3 \cdot 1 = 0\end{cases}$$
So, whatever $c_1, c_2, c_3$ make it so that $(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0)$, we also know they solve this system. Further solving of the system tells us
$$\begin{cases}c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 + c_2 \cdot 0 = 0 \\ c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 = 0 \\
c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + c_3 \cdot 1 = 0\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} c_1 = 0 \\ c_2 = 0 \\ c_3 = 0.\end{cases}$$
Putting these implications together, we get
$$(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0) \implies \begin{cases} c_1 = 0 \\ c_2 = 0 \\ c_3 = 0,\end{cases}$$
which is to say, $\{1, \sin(x), \sin(2x)\}$ is linearly independent.
That's the proof. It's a bit wordier than necessary, but it is valid. Our assumption that $c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0$ as functions, is very restrictive. Very few values of $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are going to make that equation an identity, and as we have proven, $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$ are the only ones.

Now, what happens when we don't choose our values of $x$ so well? We could choose, for example, $x = 0$, $x = \pi$ and $x = 2\pi$. What would this give us? We would know that
\begin{align*}
(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot \sin(x) + c_3 \cdot \sin(2x) = 0) &\implies \begin{cases}c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 + c_2 \cdot 0 = 0 \\
c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 + c_2 \cdot 0 = 0 \\
c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot 0 + c_3 \cdot 0 = 0\end{cases} \\
&\iff c_1 = 0.
\end{align*}
This tells us that $c_1 = 0$, but doesn't say anything about $c_2$ or $c_3$. Can we conclude from this that $\{1, \sin(x), \sin(2x)\}$ is linearly dependent?
No, we can't. This conclusion doesn't tell us that $c_2$ and $c_3$ could be anything, it just tells us, for sure, that $c_1$ must be $0$. Other pieces of information that we've rejected could (and do) tell us more about $c_2$ and $c_3$. It tells us that we need more information from our assumption. Yes, we know that $0 + c_2\sin(x) + c_3\sin(2x) = 0$ holds at $x = 0, \pi, 2\pi$ for any $c_2$ and $c_3$, but what about the other values of $x$? Could they tell us more?
This method of choosing finite $x$ can be (and has been) used to show linear independence of functions. It cannot be used to show linear dependence. The implication flows one way, and just because you get stuck at the conclusion $c_1 = 0$ and nothing else, does not mean you have all the information.

Let us take the vector space of continuous functions on a given set $X$ and denote it by $C(X)$. A subset $\{f_1, f_2, \dotsc, f_n\}$ in $C(X)$ is said to be linearly independent if whenever there exist scalars $c_1, c_2, \dotsc, c_n $ such that $c_1f_1+c_2f_2+\dotsc + c_nf_n=0$ i.e. $c_1f_1(x)+c_2f_2(x)+\dotsc + c_nf_n(x)=0$ for every $x \in X$, then $c_1=c_2=\dotsc =c_n=0$.
In your example, three different values of $x$ are choosen since three are three parameters $c_1, c_2, c_3$ which in turn corresponds to a $3 \times 3$ linear homogeneous system.

Isn't it possible the we would get non zero values of c1, c2 or c3 if we choose a different set of values for x and hence would fail linear independence? Does it matter for the proof? Please explain.

If you find others values for $c_1,c_2,c_3$, your relationship will not be satisfied for the values of $x$ you have taken.

@user763322 it is not possible in this case what you said otherwise the given set would have been linearly dependent.

Okay so, what is the reason behind it as here are infinity many values possible for sin(x) and sin(2x) between -1 and 1? How do you come up with this? How can we be so sure by just calculating c1, c2, and c3 for 3 particular values of x (and hence only 3 particular set of values for sin(x) and sin(2x))?

@user763322 there is no fixed algorithm. It is a hit and trial method. There is a better method to check linear independence via wroskian. Please find the attached link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian

@Curious Okay....now that seems a bit complicated. And quite time consuming because of calculating too many derivatives as the number of functions in the subset increase. Is it this the only way...? Thanks...it helped.

@user763322 You should flag the answer to your question if you find it correct and helpful.

In case of system of linear equation with $n$ unknown we need at least $n$ equation to check the uniqueness of solution of the system of equation.Here we have three unknowns so we take three values of $x$ to form system of linear equation having three equations so that we can find values(Unique or non unique)of $c_1$,$c_2$,$c_3$ which will further help in determining independence or dependence of those three vector with the help of definition of dependence or independence of vector.

I understand that but my doubt is that solution for c1, c2 and c3 is trivial in this case. If we had chosen a different set of values for x, could we still get the same trivial solution i.e. c1 = c2 = c3 = 0 (which we will always get for a homogeneous system), or we could get some other non-zero values also? Will it affect the proof? thanks...

You can chose more then three values of $x$ to solve this problem but it will only increase the complexity of problem.It will only increase the number of rows in rref while final answer remains  same.

If you had chosen different set of values for $x$, you will get same  solution and it will not affect the proof.

Well, why would that be though no matter what we choose there shall always be at least 1 one solution i.e. c1=c2=c3=0 as the resulting system would be homogeneous. But it may be possible that the for some values of x that might yield non-zero solutions as well. If not, what is the reason for that? Will it affect the proof? Should the proof reflect this?

If three functions $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are linearly dependent, then there are constants $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ (at least one $c_i\neq0$) such that $c_1f_1+c_2f_2+c_3f_3$ is the zero function. Now, what that means is
$$c_1f_1(x)+c_2f_2(x)+c_3f_3(x)=0$$
for all $x$. Now, in your case, you set $x=\pi$, so the equation gives $c_1=0$, then $x=\pi/2$ giving $c_2=0$, and finally $x=\pi/4$ giving $c_3=0$. But this means that they are not linearly dependent, as we started with the assumption that at least one of $c_i$s is nonzero. Hence, they must be linearly independent.
Hope this helps. :)
